# Google Maps Distance Matrix with more than 2 elements returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm really questioning my sanity here and hoping someone can help.

Querying the google maps distance matrix with 2 elements works fine (1 origin, 2 destinations):

```
$ curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=Victoria+BC|San+Francisco&key=$GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"
```

With 3 or more elements, I always get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error:

```
$ curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=Victoria+BC|San+Francisco|New+York&key=$GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.",
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Based on the [standard usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits) (pasted below), I shouldn't see this error with a single request of only 3 elements (1 origin and 3 destinations).

> Each query sent to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is limited by
> the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the
> number of destinations defines the number of elements.
>
> - 2,500 free elements per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and    server-side queries.
> - Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per    request.
> - 100 elements per request.
> - 100 elements per second,    calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

The pattern holds regardless of the order of the 2 queries. The 2-element query always succeeds and the 3-element query always fails. Any ideas?

Edit: Just tried this with 3 origins and 1 destination with the same result, so it definitely seems to be related to the number of elements in a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, it looks like a bug in how this API enforces custom quota limits. If you reset the limits back to the defaults (via the developer console/api dashboard), you should get the expected behavior:

- Elements per day: 2,500
- Elements per 100 seconds: 10,000
- Elements per user: Unlimited

Comment: Elements per day: 2,500 => thats for one API key?

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. I had success with the following cuts: 
    Elements per day: 10,000; Elements per minute: 1,000; Elements per user per minute: Unlimited.